# C# HttpWebRequest POST Login, then GET other site

Tags: c#, authentication, post, get, httpwebrequest

I wrote two HttpWebrequests to login and get HTML from a site.
The Cookies of the first response are catched in a CookieContainer and used in the second request.
Currently it's catching 3 cookies.
The response of the second request has statusCode 302 found/redirect.
When opened the page on my browser and used ctrl+u on the page, i can find the "var login_user" filled with my data.
The login with the first request looks to work, because it redirects me after login to the specified url, but in the HTML content of its response, I can find the "var login_user=null".
Can someone help me to get a statusCode OK on second response to get its HTML content?

```
        string loginUrl = @"https://id2.g-portal.com/login?redirect=https://www.g-portal.com/auth/login?redirectAfterLogin/https://www.g-portal.com/de/";
        string logDataUrl = @"https://www.g-portal.com/server/.../logs";

        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        // POST request to login
        HttpWebRequest loginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginUrl);
        loginRequest.Method = "POST";
        loginRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        loginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        loginRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0";
        loginRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

        byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("login=" + username + "&password=" + password);
        loginRequest.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
        using (Stream postStream = loginRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        }
        using (HttpWebResponse loginResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loginRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            Uri uri1 = loginResponse.ResponseUri;
            var status1 = loginResponse.StatusCode; // is OK
            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(loginResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string loginHtmlContent = responseReader.ReadToEnd();   
                foreach (Cookie cookie in loginResponse.Cookies)
                {
                    cookieContainer.Add(cookie);
                }
            }
        }

        // GET request for logs
        HttpWebRequest logDataRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(logDataUrl);
        logDataRequest.Method = "GET";
        logDataRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        logDataRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0";
        logDataRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        logDataRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        string resultHTMLcontent = string.Empty;
        using (HttpWebResponse logDataResponse = (HttpWebResponse)logDataRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            Uri uri2 = logDataResponse.ResponseUri;
            var status2 = logDataResponse.StatusCode;   // is Found
            Console.WriteLine("Log data request succesfully");
            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(logDataResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                resultHTMLcontent = responseReader.ReadToEnd(); // is empty
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using Selenium instead?

Comment: @mjwills No I have never worked with it, just read about it yesterday when i was looking for a way to select on a dropdown list, because that's what i will have to do on the site of the second request.

Comment: Try to enable auto-redirection (`[HttpWebRequest].AllowAutoRedirect = true;`). If it doesn't follow the redirection, take the `Location` header and follow it yourself (set the Referer, in case you have more than one Hop).

Comment: I already did both, it redirects me to https://www.g-portal.com/gamecloud same way like opening the server url while you are not logged in. That's why it is AllowAutoRedirect = false.

Comment: That's not the issue. Your login procedure is incomplete. You have to pass all the INPUT elements (including the hidden ones) and their values. If you don't, you're redirected to the same login page, over and over. BTW, you need this: `CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();` declared as a Field, outside the the login proc, otherwise your Cookies are not preserved between calls. It's not clear where that declaration belongs to.

Comment: I'm not sure which one of the two requests you are talking about. The POST request has allowAutoRedirect = true by default and redirects me to the page specified at the "?redirectAfterLogin" param (look at the long loginUrl) and the response also doesn't say anymore that I'am unable to login, so i think I'am filling all needed InputElements.
The GET request with enabled redirection redirects me to /gamecloud but that's not my target page.
CookieContainer changed to field.